# Offset from end / reverse offset?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to get the "offset" from end row? Like some kind of negative offset maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Get the offset of what?  What do you mean by "end row"?  And example or two would help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about offset in the "limit/offset" sense, the traditional way is to change your ORDER BY to reverse the results. Then OFFSET becomes offset from the end of the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. `mysql_num_rows()-rowoffset`

**Edit:**

I take from the comments to this answer, that it is not fully understood, that the Database has no way of knowing, how many rows it will finally find, while processing those rows, it already found - so outside of some tricks that end up in running the same query twice (which I consider not to be agood thing), the **number of rows still not found** is not accessible in a row. Thsi is, why I suggest to use the consuming environment as above: `mysql_num_rows()` coming from after the query, and `rowoffset` coming from inside the query.

Comment: e.g. http://at2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php (or whatever language you use). The row offset calculated by incrementing a variable on every row fetch.

Comment: Thanks; wasn't the original question about SQL or MySQL?

Comment: Yup. It was. And by extension on some sort of environment, that consumes the output of the (My)SQL - solving a problem like this one is a job for the sourrounding environment, as the Database clearly isn't in a position to know the number of rows it will finally find, while processing those, it already found. The consuming environment is.